# How to increase the size of venn diagram workspace

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the venn diagram code from here in my angular2+ code -

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpham92/h04sknus/

code

**app.js**

```
var sets;

sets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sets"));

  console.log("sets=",sets)

var chart = venn.VennDiagram();
d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="venn"></div>
```

When the number of nodes increase , the names overlap like this -

[image: Venn diagram workspace]

Please help to increase the workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the workspace (svg) size like so:

```
var chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(1200).height(500);
```

As you can see in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h04sknus/503/) you've linked.

If you can't hardcoded the width and height, I guess you can calculate them before assigning them.

Comment: sorry. I get this error - Uncaught TypeError: selection.datum is not a function

Comment: Figured out. venn.VennDiagram().width(2500).height(2400);

Comment: You are correct, I've edit my answer, Is it working now?